# Android OpenCV : No resource identifier found for attribute 'camera_id' in package

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I have OpenCV and Android set up in my Eclipse. The following is one of my layout files:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        opencv:show_fps="true"
        opencv:camera_id="any" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Eclipse compiler complains about:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'show_fps' in package 
No resource identifier found for attribute 'camera_id' in package
```

Comment: I had this same issue with Android Studio. I had to compile the OpenCVLibraryXXX project/module to fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Please add following resource file in your project's values directory :

```
attrs.xml
```

with following content :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name = "CameraBridgeViewBase" >
       <attr name="show_fps" format="boolean"/>
       <attr name="camera_id" format="integer" >
          <enum name="any" value="-1" />
          <enum name="back" value="0" />
          <enum name="front" value="1" />
       </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The two previously given answers to this question, in my opinion, are bandaids to the actual problem. When I encountered this error message, I needed to change some project properties.

1. Right click project and select Properties
2. Select 'Android' in the tree control
3. Make sure the OpenCV library is present and has a green check mark next to it in the 'Library' section (seen in the image below)

[image: Successfully linked OpenCV Library]

If the OpenCV library is not present or has a red X next to it, you need to fix the Library dependency. To do this:

1. Remove broken library (if necessary)
2. Click Add and select OpenCV Library
3. If OpenCV library is not present, you need to add the library to the project

Answer (score 0):

you did not given value for this variables or not declare in opencv class..

```
    opencv {

   show_fps="true"
   camera_id="any"

     }

  First assign the those two variables globally with necessary values....
```